# I build a chat application in based on Android, I wonder to know how whatsapp could run smoothly in weak connection like 2G even edge?

Tags: android, chat, whatsapp

Our server using ejabber, and in Android using smack.

Application run smoothly in > 3G. But, when in weak connection like 2G, the xmpp connection even cannot connect into the server.

What is the problem? is the server connection issues?, i know about LZMA2, should we implement that or anyone suggest?

Comment: XMPP protocol might be your solution

Comment: @war_Hero yes, we did. we use XMPP which i used SMACK in android and ejabberd in server.